# How to center continued text using PdfKit?

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

I have this code:

```js
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const QRCode = require("qrcode");
const fs = require("fs");

const exec = async () => {
  const doc = new PDFDocument({ layout: "landscape" });
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("output.pdf"));

  for (let pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= 1000; pageNumber++) {
    const url = await QRCode.toDataURL("I am a url!");

    doc
      .image(url, 10, 100, {
        width: 420,
        height: 420,
        align: "center",
        valign: "center",
      })

    doc
      .font("Helvetica")
      .fontSize(50)
      .fillColor("#000")
      .text(`Item `, 465, 200, { continued: true })
      .fontSize(55)
      .font("Courier-Bold")
      .fillColor("#1b83c5")
      .text(`${pageNumber}`);

    doc
      .font("Helvetica-Bold")
      .fontSize(40)
      .fillColor("#000")
      .text("Order and Pay", 420, 320);

    doc.addPage();
  }

  doc.end();
};

exec();
```

Which would produce something like this:
[image]

It looks centered and all, but as pages increase it will no longer be centered since the numbers are fixed.

[image]

I saw in the docs that there's an `align` property, but the docs didn't explain how to handle continued text.

Any working examples?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little late, but I found a solution battling with the same problem:

First you need to create a constant with the width of the container you want to center your text in: (this value you have to calculate or invent, but it's easy to do that)

```
const containerWidth = 100 // as an example
```

Then, you need to create a variable that contains a plain string that contains all the text you want to center, in your example:

```
var appendedText = `Item ${pageNumber}`
```

To finish, you need to use pdf-kit's function: widthOfString, and add the text in the document as follows:

```
const xOffset = 465 // The original X offset value
doc
.text(`Item `, xOffset + (containerWidth / 2) - (doc.widthOfString(appendedText) / 2), 200, { continued: true })
.text(`${pageNumber}`);
```

Removed the text styling lines for clarity, but you have to add them later.